# javascript exec function

Tags: javascript, function

I saw a piece of sample code like this in a javascript code.

```
    exec: function(myString){
    var: link1=link2;
    editor1=editor2;
    link1.execute();
    },
```

I would like to know why the syntax is like this :  exec: function()?  does it mean just to execute this function at run time?  Why there is no function name here?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look into finding a basic JavaScript introduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of an object declaration.  The `exec` has no special meaning, it's just the name of a property in an object.

```
var obj = {
    exec: function(myString){
        var link1=link2;  // there shouldn't be a  `:` here.
        editor1=editor2;
        link1.execute();
    },
    name: 'Joe'
};
```

Then you can do:

```
obj.exec('abc');
```